# vba find first non-blank row

Tags: vba, excel, row

I'm new to VBA and struggling with the piece of code.

I need to find the first non-empty row where the conditions are simultaneously met. There must be text in col B and C and number in col D and G (all 4 conditions must be met).

I'd very grateful for help
s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to nest [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method as follows:

```
Sub main()

    With Worksheets("Conditions") '<--| change "Conditions" to your actual worksheet name
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) '<-- refer to column "B" cells down to last non empty one
            With .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<-- refer to its "text" cells only
                With .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<-- refer to adjacent column "text" cells only
                    With .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<-- refer to adjacent column "number" cells only
                        With .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) '<-- refer to adjacent column "number" cells only
                            MsgBox .Cells(1, 1).row '<--| get first "multifiltered" cells row
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

you may need to add test before each `SpecialCells()` to check that "current" column actually has some text/numbers value, using a mix of [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840324.aspx) and [`CountA()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838049.aspx) method

Comment: @salti, did you try this?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: you just [click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). thank you

Answer (score 3):

write like below code using and if & and  note:lastrow is end of column values.

```
for i = 1 to lastrow
 if cells(i,"b")<>"" and cells(i,"c")<>"" and isnumber(cells(i,"d"))= true and isnumber(cells(i,"g"))= true then
 'do something
 end if
next i
```

Comment: VBA doesn't have an `IsNumber` function, it is `IsNumeric`.  (It's `IsNumber` in Excel.  And they work slightly differently.)